# Change the navigation of inviteRedeemUrl in Invitation Email: Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2b

I created an email invitation using Microsoft Graph to a azure ad application. IN the email that was being received on clicking the  Get Started [(Elements of Email Invite)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/invitation-email-elements)element it is being redirected  to the signin page not the sign up page of the application that i want to redirect to.

How can I  disable that element or override the Redeem url?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are using [**Create invitation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0) from Microsoft Graph? If so, you could specify the `inviteRedirectUrl` in the request body to customize where you want your users to land after redemption.

```http
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/invitations
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 551

{
  "invitedUserEmailAddress": "yyy@test.com",
  "inviteRedirectUrl": "https://myapp.com/xxxxxx"
}
```

For more details, see [**Azure Active Directory B2B collaboration API and customization**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/customize-invitation-api).

Answer (score 0):

> IN the email that was being received on clicking the Get Started
>   (Elements of Email Invite)element it is being redirected to the signin
>   page not the sign up page of the application that i want to redirect
>   to.

In the invitation, it uses the invitation manager to create an invite, in order to add an external user to the organization. After making the invitation, the invited user doesn't need to sign up and already be a member/guest user in the azure ad.
[image]
For the details, you could read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/invitation?view=graph-rest-1.0).

Comment: If I want to redirect to some other url is it possible?

Comment: That is impossible. I tried to change the invitedRedeemUrl to other urls not same with invitedRedirectUrl, but the result not changes.

Comment: I tried the same and the invited redeem url value is not changing.